# Configure MX for SendGrid Inbound Parse and G Suite (Google Apps) on multiple environments

Tags: email, dns, google-apps, sendgrid, mx-record

I have an app that runs on staging at `stg.mydomain.com` and production on `mydomain.com`. The core of the app is the ability for people to run surveys via email, where people can reply to the email with their answers. This is handled via SendGrid's Inbound Parse.

What I now want to do is configure Mailchimp so I can email my customers from something like `benjamin@mydomain.com`, and get their replies there too. So I'm looking into setting up G Suite (formerly Google Apps) to do this.

I understand what I probably need to do is move Inbound Parse to a subdomain like `mail.mydomain.com` – but I'm not sure how this would work with the staging environment. Would it be `mail.stg.mydomain.com`?

Basically I need emails to `benjamin@mydomain.com` to come to my inbox, but emails to `uuid@mydomain.com` or `uuid@mail.mydomain.com` to go to my app via SendGrid.

How do I configure my CNAME and MX records to make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error and re-reading SendGrid's documentation, I ended up moving Inbound Parse to a subdomain (`mail`), which then freed up the root for Google Apps.

Now I have this configuration in Cloudflare for MX:

```
MX    mail            mx.sendgrid.net
MX    mail.stg        mx.sendgrid.net
MX    mydomain.com    aspmx.l.google.com
MX    mydomain.com    ...l.google.com
```

Now when I send an email from the app I include the `mail` subdomain and continue to use an environment variable for setting the domain name to either `stg` or the root.

```
mail(to: email_address,
         from: "#{company} <questions@mail.#{Figaro.env.domain}>",
         reply_to: "#{uuid}@mail.#{Figaro.env.domain}")
```

Lastly, in SendGrid, I changed the whitelabeled domain and the Inbound Parse configuration to match `mail.mydomain.com`.